# Contador en array $_SESSION

Tags: php, html

estoy aprendiendo un poco a programar y estoy teniendo un problema que no consigo solucionar.
Mi idea es almacenar en el array $_SESSION, un contador, que me cuente las respuestas correctas de un pequeño test, además en otras posiciones del array almaceno los datos que el usuario vaya seleccionando en cada control (checkbox,text...).... Un ayuda me serviría de mucho porque no entiendo que lo que está sucediento, ya que en la segunda pagina si lo lleva bien, pero en el momento que quiero evaluar un string, me lo cuenta como positivo. No entiendo demasiado de cosas más complejas

```html
<?php
session_start(); 

$_SESSION['Nusu']=$_REQUEST['nombre'];
$_SESSION['contador']=0;

    ?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>

 <title>Pregunta 1 - AHS</title></head>
<body>
<h1> <?php echo $_SESSION['Nusu']; ?> ¿Quiénes son estos dos?</h1>
<img src="images/EvanTaisa.jpeg" alt="ImagenPersonajes"/><br/>
    
<form name="personajes" action="pregunta2.php" method="POST">

 <input type="radio" name="personaje" value="misty">
 Misty y Tate <br/>
 <input type="radio" name="personaje" value="violet" >
 Violet y Tate
    
<br/><br/>
 <button type="submit" name="enviar">Enviar</button>

</form>

</body> 
</html>
```

Y en la siguiente página:

```html
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['per']=$_REQUEST['personaje'];
if(isset($_REQUEST['enviar'])){
    $person= $_REQUEST['personaje'];
}
    if($person=="violet"){
        $_SESSION['contador']++;
    }
    
echo  $_SESSION['contador'];

?>
<html>
<head><title> Pregunta 2 -AHS</title></head>
<body>
    <h1> <?php echo $_SESSION['Nusu']; ?> ¿Cuál es el nombre de la segunda temporada?</h1>
  
 <form name="temporada" action="pregunta3.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" required maxlength="20" size="40" name="tem">
   <button type="submit" name="enviar">Enviar</button>
</form>
</body> 
</html>
```

El problema es que en la primera página me suma el contador en $_SESSION['contador'] correctamente, pero la siguiente al tratar de averiguar si $_person=='violet',  me suma 1 siempre, seleccione o no la respuesta correcta.

```html
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_REQUEST['enviar'])){
 $tem= $_REQUEST['tem'];
    }

  if($tem=="Assylym"||"assylum"){
        $_SESSION['contador']++;
    }

echo  $_SESSION['contador'];

 

?>
```

Comment: Intenta cambiarle el nombre a los 2 campos de tipo radio y ponle name="personaje[]"

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que si elige 'misty' como respuesta te suma el valor del contador? Yo hice una prueba y solo me suma cuando se elige la opción 'violet'

Comment: Si, exacto... pues sigo con el problema pero al ver que a ud si le funciona, el problema creo que lo puedo tener en la siguiente página con otro bloque php, en el que también evaluo string..

Comment: Puedes cambiar  if($tem=="Assylym"||"assylum"){ por  if(strtolower($tem) =="assylum"){

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas lo que me indicas solucionó el problema, muchas gracias :D